# xslt transformation links

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, hyperlink

I am trying to figure out how to change a html page using an xslt transformation on an xml file, by clicking on an element in the table.
I have looked around and couldn't find an answer, here is a simple code and I would like to know how to change the page and display something:
I don't think it is necessary for you to read the code except for the the final one, the XSLT. I have added the other sections of the code in case they also need some changing.

XSD:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com"
 xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com">

 <xs:element name="Table">
 <xs:complexType>
 <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
 <xs:element ref="Person"/>
 </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
 <xs:element name="Person">
 <xs:complexType>
 <xs:all maxOccurs="1">
 <xs:element ref="Name"/>
 <xs:element minOccurs="1" ref="Age"/>
 </xs:all>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Name">
 <xs:complexType>
 <xs:sequence>
 <xs:element maxOccurs="1" ref="theName"/>
 <xs:element maxOccurs="1" ref="Description"/>
 </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
 <xs:element name="theName" type="xs:string"/>
 <xs:element name="Description" type="xs:string"/>
 <xs:element abstract="false" name="Age" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
 </xs:schema>
```

So I created two elements, theName and the age. Name is composed of the String TheName and the String Description. Age is just a positiveinteger. Now I created the XML file which just chooses two different People:

XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="try.xsl"?>
 <Table xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3schools.com try.xsd">
 <Person>
 <Name>
 <theName>Thomas</theName>
 <Description>He is a nice guy</Description>
 </Name>
 <Age>10</Age>
 </Person>

 <Person>
 <Name>
 <theName>Peter</theName>
 <Description>He is good at swimming</Description>
 </Name>
 <Age>12</Age>
 </Person>

 </Table>
```

My transformation now is to make a table with the name of the people in function of there age:

XSLT:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <xsl:stylesheet

 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ws="http://www.w3schools.com"
 version="1.0"> 

 <xsl:template match="/">
 <html>

 <table border="2">
 <tr bgcolor="red">
 <th>Name</th>
 <th>Age</th>
 </tr>
 <xsl:for-each select="ws:Table/ws:Person">
 <tr>

 <td><xsl:value-of select="ws:Name/ws:theName"/></td>
 <td><xsl:value-of select="ws:Age"/></td>

 </tr>
 </xsl:for-each>
 </table>
```

This is where I need help, how do I display the description of the person if I click on the name of the person. So basically if I click on Thomas I want to display "He is a nice guy", and if I click on Peter I want to display "he is a good swimmer".

```
 </html>
 </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried searching for javascript/CSS solutions on how to show/hide information on mouse-clicks?

Comment: no, isn't it possible with xslt?

Comment: (I have never used javascript)

Comment: This is a javascript question -- not an xslt one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XSLT change page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258757/xslt-change-page)

Answer (score 0):

The XSLT script will produce a text file, in this case a HTML (web) page, that in turn will be interpreted by another application (a web browser). For information on how you can create a dynamic web page with slick interactions, please review tutorials on [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) and [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript).